# How to draw the correct table?

Tags: word-problem

> $\frac{3}{5}$ of a mixture that has $\%40$ of alcohol is poured. If we put water as amount of poured mixture into the mixture, what would be the alcohol ratio?

If there's $\%40$ of alcohol, then we need to have $\%60$ of water. However, I couldn't keep this on with given info. Below is a table which I tried to draw.

\begin{array}{l c c c}
\text{mixture} & \text{water (l)} & \text{alcohol (l)} & \text{total (l)}\\ \hline
\text{solution 1} & 60 & 40 & 20\\
\text{solution 2} & 20 & 0 & 20\\
\text{solution 3} & 80 & 0 & 80\\ \hline
\text{new mixture} & 160 & 40 & 200
\end{array}

Where solution 2 represents to the poured mixture. Hence we get $160 \cdot \frac{100}{100} = \boxed{\%16}$

Regards!

Comment: An accurate answer requires a knowledge of chemistry.  For example, mixing 500ml or water and 500ml of alcohol creates less than 1l of the mixture.

Comment: @badjohn Let's solve this problem mathematically. It doesn't matter whether it creates less than 1l of the mixture. We might assume that it creates 1l

Comment: If I understand correctly, adding 60% (600mL) of water to a mixture of 1000mL of 40% alcohol, will result in 400mL of alcohol in a 1600mL mixture, which is now 25%, Is this what you were asking?

Comment: @PhilH Yes, take a look at the table I drew. You will see what I tried to mean.

Comment: Can't anyone give an answer?

Comment: Hey, Isn't there anyone?

Comment: I guess that you have not managed to interest anyone.  Also, I still find the question rather unclear.